# How to run a python cmd inside a bash cmd over ssh

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, terminal, python

When I run the following in my bash terminal, it works fine.

`$ bash -c "python -c \"print 'helloworld'\""` ---> helloworld

However when I try to do this over ssh, it give me nothing, can someone help shed some light on this issue?

`$ ssh meeee@10.145.70.90 "bash -c \"python -c \"print 'helloworld'\"\""` --> nothing

Comment: by the way, this is python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not quoting right. Your command

> ```
> ssh meeee@10.145.70.90 "bash -c \"python -c \"print 'helloworld'\"\""
> ```

runs this on the remote side:

```
bash -c "python -c "print 'helloworld'""
```

which is equivalent to

```
bash -c "python -c print" 'helloworld'
```

which runs `python -c print`, which prints an empty line. (Note: `helloworld` acts like [this](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690).)

---

To quote right you need more backslashes. This:

```
ssh meeee@10.145.70.90 "bash -c \"python -c \\\"print 'helloworld'\\\"\""
```

runs the following on the remote side:

```
bash -c "python -c \"print 'helloworld'\""
```

which is exactly what you wanted.

Check [this question on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690). It is intended to help in similar cases.

---

You most likely don't need `bash -c` at all. This code should work in a local shell:

```
python -c "print 'helloworld'"
```

so this will probably work:

```
ssh meeee@10.145.70.90 "python -c \"print 'helloworld'\""
```

Probably, because the SSH server will run the command using the shell chosen by meeee as their login shell. In some exotic cases it may not run `python -c` properly. But since you're expecting it to run `bash -c`, it should also run `python -c`

Comment: Hello thank you for your response, I need bash -c because the user will be login into a different shell, I tried your answer but it still doesn't work.  My actual python statement is more complex than this but I need to at least get a simple command working before trying the more complex one.   

`ssh meeee@10.145.70.90 "bash -c \"python -c \\\"print 'helloworld'\\\"\""`

Comment: @KNNguyen Two things: (1) My point is if you expect `bash -c` to work in the different shell then you may expect `python -c` to work as well without `bash` in between. (2) Does `bash -c "python -c \"print 'helloworld'\""` work for meee after they log in via SSH to their interactive shell?

Comment: Yes if I log into the box and do `bash -c "python -c \"print 'helloworld'\""`, it will work.

Comment: @KNNguyen When you say `it still doesn't work`, can you provide more details? What happens?

Comment: Interesting, basically tested with 2 users, 1 is root, another is meee which has less priviledge, for BOTH of the user, if I ssh into the box and do `bash -c "python -c \"print 'helloworld'\""`, I see the output helloworld, however if I run `meeee@10.145.70.90"bash -c \"python -c \\\"print 'helloworld'\\\"\""`, I get nothing, but if I run `root@10.145.70.90"bash -c \"python -c \\\"print 'helloworld'\\\"\""`, I get helloworld.

Comment: the meee user by default will log into the tmsh shell https://clouddocs.f5.com/cli/tmsh-reference/latest/general/tmsh.html

Comment: @KNNguyen Please confirm you can run `bash -c "python -c \"print 'helloworld'\""` by typing this exact command directly in tmsh. I'm not sure. If it was the case then sole `bash` would be enough to get to Bash; but I found information one needs to invoke `run /util bash` to get to Bash from tmsh.

Comment: Yes, literally if I were to ssh into the box as meee, I'll be in the tmsh shell and if I paste `bash -c "python -c \"print 'helloworld'\""`, it will output helloworld, but if I do meee@10.145.70.90"bash -c \"python -c \\\"print 'helloworld'\\\"\"", I get nothing.

Comment: I think there might be some additional parsing differences, if I do `root@10.145.70.90"bash -cv \"python -c \\\"print 'helloworld'\\\"\""`, I get `hostname () {  echo -e "Use the TMOS shell utility to make changes to the system configuration.\nFor more information, see \"tmsh help sys global-settings.\"" 1>&2;
 return 1
}
tzselect () {  echo -e "Use the TMOS shell utility to make changes to the system configuration.\nFor more information, see \"tmsh help sys ntp.\"" 1>&2;
 return 1
}
python -c "print 'helloworld'"
helloworld`

Comment: if I do mee@10.145.70.90"bash -cv \"python -c \\\"print 'helloworld'\\\"\"", I got a bunch more output and then it ends with `
  # for bash and zsh, only if no alias is already set
  alias vi >/dev/null 2>&1 || alias vi=vim
fi
/usr/bin/id -u
# Initialization script for bash and sh
# export AFS if you are in AFS environment
alias which='alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
# vim:ts=4:sw=4
# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions
python -c print`

Comment: @KNNguyen This looks like a quirk of tmsh. Both answers are good in solving the quoting issue. Your question doesn't even mention tmsh, its quirk is a *separate* issue. I wouldn't change the question to cover the two issues. One issue -- one question. I don't know tmsh enough to tell if it's on-topic here on Unix&Linux.

Comment: @KNNguyen Is there a way to get from `bash` to `tmsh`? If so, then maybe I have a sketch of a solution for you.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer, I'll give a thumb up for both answers.  I guess my main goal is to log in as a user, start a subprocess bash shell and run the python command there, get the output and then exit, let me know if there is better way to do it.

Comment: yes inside tmsh, if you type bash, then you will inside the a subprocess bash shell, then if you type exit, then you'll be back out into the tmsh shell.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh meeee@10.145.70.90 "$(cat <<'EOT'
bash -c "python -c \"print 'helloworld'\""
EOT
)"
```

I have the idea of a simple function/utility which should help avoid the quoting nightmare with multiple embedded commands like this, stay tuned ;-)

Comment: Oh! Maybe your idea will make a good answer to [this](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690). If it's really good I will consider expanding the scope of the question ("single-quote or escape" -> "single-quote or escape or otherwise protect").

Comment: Can you explain this a little more, what does cat << 'EOT' do?

Comment: It creates a [here-document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents), inside which you can paste the remote command as is, without having to escape anything. Since you want to pass the data as a string, not as input, the here-document is embedded in a double-quoted [command subtitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution).

Comment: Dude this is actually pretty genius!